# Symfony2 Form from multiple classes

Tags: forms, symfony, upload, doctrine, persist

I have a class Article that contain an array of classes Step and Step contain multiple classes Media.

Idea is that an article can contain several steps and each step can contain several images.

I need to implement a form for easy upload and persistence with Doctrine.

I need some advice about how to make with jQuery possibility to upload multiple images which appear to an article and persist with Doctrine.

When I try to add to form:

```
            ->add('files','file',
        array(
                "label"     => "Files",
                "required"  => FALSE,
                "attr"      => array(
                "accept"    => "image/*",
                "multiple"  => "multiple",
        )
```

I receive an error:

```
Neither property "files" nor method "getFiles()" nor method "isFiles()" exists in class      "Ift\DesignBundle\Entity\Article"
```

In Entity Article I have

```
 protected $steps;
```

That is in relationship with class Steps (OneToMany).
In Steps is a property:

```
protected $media;
```

That represent an image and is in relation with Steps OneToMany.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just don't have setter and getter for your private or protected propery $files, or you don't have this property at all